How to constrain a general mapping (from a multiset to a multiset) to a multirelation?
A multiset is a function, that assign a multiplicity (non-negative integer) to all elements of an underlying (universe) set. Let $A$ be a set, then $m: A \to \mathbb N_0$ is a multiset. $\mu A$ denotes the set of all multisets over $A$.
A multirelation over two sets $A$ and $B$ is a function $R: (A \times B) \to \mathbb N_0$. An application of a multirelation to a multiset $\alpha \in \mu A$ is a multiset $\beta \in \mu B$ defined as:
$$\forall b \in B : \beta(b) := \sum_{a \in A} R(a,b) \cdot \alpha(a)$$
I am trying to answer the following question. I have two disjoint, finite, non-empty sets $A$ and $B$, and a function $S: \mu A \to \mu B$, which maps multisets over $A$ to multisets over $B$. The function $S$ must satisfy certain constrains and I want to show that because of this it must be a multirelation. What properties do I have to show $S$ must satisfy to conclude that $S$ must necessarily be a multirelation?
I know, that the mapping $S$ must be linear (addition of multisets is defined elementwise), i.e.
$$ \forall \alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mu A : S(\alpha_1) + S(\alpha_2) = S(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)$$
Is this enough to conclude that $S$ must be a multirelation? If not, what other properties must be present to make this conclusion? If possible, I am also looking for a good source, such as a textbook, which I could cite.
Thank you for your answers
